# Create multiple tables using mail merge

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have fields as below for report cards of students.

```
<<firstname>>
<<lastname>>
<<grade>>
<<totalmarks>>
```

So above fields will be one record in a mail merger perspective. I have a word document where all the report cards are placed in a table structure , the fields inserted in a table like below format

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Fist Name | `<<firstname>>` |
| Last Name | `<<lastname>>` |
| Grade | `<<grade>>` |
| Total Marks | `<<totalmarks>>` |

Expected output

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Fist Name | Jacob |
| Last Name | Thomas |
| Grade | A |
| Total Marks | 93 |

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Fist Name | Mariya |
| Last Name | John |
| Grade | A+ |
| Total Marks | 100 |

Is it possible to create tables based on the mail merge fields in one single document, so that I don't have to draw a table for every student record?  Every record will create a table just below the previous one.

Comment: You my want to use a Catalog or Directory merge. See Paul Edstein's tutorial: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[updated below - Maybe a mail merge more like labels - where each repeated record (in this case your summary table) is in a separate row with "Next Record" mergefield as well.  The "outer" table has no borders.  I just did a quick test with about a dozen "student records" and it worked for me, continuing over onto next page.]

Charles' suggestion above re Directory works - will just generate tables you want and no blanks at end.  If you change to just a single row and then insert your table inside that, including a paragraph mark within the single row above it - to act as a separator space between tables once you merge (and avoid a single space being added before "First" in subsequent rows).  For the single row, also set its properties to not allow it to break across pages, then your 4 row table will stay together on same page.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the update, this works, but for this, if I'm right I have to create tables first, my requirement is depending on the records tables have to be created and the respective records have to be filled. I cant create tables for each record that will be difficult

Comment: You just create one page (once you have the first one, just copy and paste), the mail merge will replicate the page as many times as needed, so depending on how many records you have, there could be a few blank tables at the end which you can just delete once merged.

Comment: that's a good suggestion, but that is not my requirement.

Comment: Hi Joel, see edited answer above incorporating Charles' comment re Directory merge - I think that might do the trick as per new image in answer above.